# How to configure redis to use environment variable as the dist location path?

Tags: redis

I have enabled both `aof` and `rdb` in my redis server. Redis will save the two files `appendonly.aof` and `dump.rdb` on the disk. How can I use environment variables to control the path of these two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Redis DOES NOT read these configuration from environment variables.

You CAN config these paths in the `redis.conf` file, or use the `CONFIG SET` command to dynamically set these paths.

The corresponding configuration keys are: `dir`, `dbfilename` and `appendfilename`.

**NOTE**: it seems that, by now, `appendfilename` is **NOT** supported to be dynamically changed with `CONFIG SET` command.